# How to use cdkVirtualScroll for in a simple single select mat-select

Tags: angular, angular-material

I am trying to use `cdkVirtualScroll` with `mat-select` for performance reasons.

```
<mat-select formControlName="name">
    <cdk-virtual-scroll-viewport itemSize="42" [style.height.px]="5*42">
        <mat-option *ckdVirtualFor="let option of ($options | async)>{{option.value}}</mat-option>
    </cdk-virtual-scroll-viewport>
</mat-select>
```

This works but has multiple issues:

1. When the select is closed, the selected option is not visible. It is only visible when it is one of the first 5 options.
2. Truncate on overflow is not working

Stackblitz: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-12xmbp-s9pund?file=src/app/cdk-virtual-scroll-overview-example.html

How do I fix these issues?

Comment: I'm not into Material at all, but thanks to your stackblitz it is apparent to me that the `itemSize` property is set too high in your example. It probably calculates the scroll position where it needs to load more items based on that. If you decrease it from `50` to let's say `30`, it scrolls smoothly.

Comment: @MikeS. that was kinda stupid indeed:)

Comment: I tought it's normal behavior because MatSelect gets their options from `QueryList<_MatOptionBase>`. And because initially selected <mat-otpion> is not instantiated yet <mat-select> has no data to show for selection. Possibly you can scroll the viewport to initial position so the virtual scroll instantiates programmatically selected option and populates QueryList with matching option.

Answer (score 1):

For the first issue, setting the `itemSize` to 1 seems to fix it.

```
 <cdk-virtual-scroll-viewport
      itemSize="1"
      [style.height.px]="5*42"
      minBufferPx="400"
      maxBufferPx="400"
    >
```

I found this solution here: https://github.com/angular/components/issues/24943

For the truncate, this fixed it in your stackblitz:

```
::ng-deep .cdk-virtual-scroll-content-wrapper {
  width: 0;
}
```

The created wrapper had too large of a width. It's min width takes over when you set the width to 0. You could potentially set the max-width instead.

Here is a forked and working stackblitz:

https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-12xmbp-rwnjuf?file=src/app/cdk-virtual-scroll-overview-example.html